# Why don't these if statements work, the response to anything I say is "hey" which is the supposed to be the response for only the first if statement

Tags: node.js

So to clarify more the code is for a voice assistant but the response I get from the AI is "hey" to anything I say which means there is something wrong with the if statement in my code, any suggestions on how to fix it? In addition, the `"#callback tracker"` part in my `console.log` is meant to track what the AI responded any idea how to track and put the response on the `"#callback tracker"` part? Thanks in advance.

```
function getResponse(message, callback){
    console.log("{ User: " + message + " ||| " + " Response: " + "#callback tracker" + "}" );
    if (message == "hey" || "hello"){
        callback("hey")
    } else if (message == "What's up" || "what's good" || "what's happening"){
        callback("Nothin much")
    } else {
        callback(message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if (message == "hey" || "hello"){`

This line is always true, because it is evaluating the string `"hello"` for its truthiness, not comparing it to `message`. You are saying: if [message is equal to "hey"] or if [the object "hello" is truthy], then...

Instead, try `if (message == "hey" || message == "hello"){`.

The same applies to the logic in your `else if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate you conditions like this:

```
if (message == "hey" || message == "hello"){
     callback("hey")
} else if (message == "What's up" || message == "what's good" || message == "what's happening"){
```

Otherwise you're evaluating whether `'hello'` is true or not.